# Changing integer value of Pair(String, Integer) in dictionary

Tags: .net, vb.net, dictionary

I've created a dictionary of string, integer:

```
Private m_MonFreq As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
```

In some part of my code, I need to change the integer value of each pair, but I didn't find a way to do that quickly.

My approach didn't work:

```
    For Each nItem As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In m_MonFreq

        nItem.Value = lMax - nItem.Value

    Next
```

The error is "Property Value is Read-Only".

Can somebody tell me a good way to do this (also quickly)?

Comment: What do you mean by `also quickly` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the values in the dictionary directly by accessing it with the key again:

```
Imports System.Linq    ' for extension method .ToArray()

For Each key As String in m_MonFreq.Keys.ToArray()
    m_MonFreq(key) = lMax - m_MonFreq(key)
Next
```

Note that you have to copy the keys over to a new enumerable (an array in this case) to have another enumerator to loop through. The one from the dictionary will change by reassigning a value in the loop. So that would lead to an exception.

Comment: But then Dictionary needs to locate the item by the key value. That's not really fast.

Comment: @tmighty on the contrary, lookup is extremely fast.  `Dictionary` is optimized for fast lookup; with a hash function for your key with good distribution, lookup will be O(1) where the constant factor is basically the cost of computing the hash.

Comment: @Waescher I'm getting the System.InvalidOperationException "The collection was changed. Enumeration perhaps can't be executed". Do you know if that's something on my side or within your code?

Comment: That's true. To prevent that, you should copy the keys over to a new array with its own enumerator. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 3):

```
For Each nItem As String in m_MonFreq.Keys
    m_MonFreq(nItem) = lMax - m_MonFreq(nItem)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to use "functional" way and create new dictionary with updated values.

```
m_MonFreq = 
    m_MonFreq.ToDictionary(Function(item) item.Key, Function(item) lMax - item.Value)
```

Performance will not suffer, it differs from mutable `For` loop only in creation of new dictionary instance. Which in 99.99% of cases will never be bottle neck of your performance.

But you get rid of all problems caused by mutating existed objects.